# How can I get all pull requests Ids (from merged commits) for a given commit Id using VSTS Git API for C#

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

If I have a commit that was merged to 20 branches (can have 20 corresponding Pull requests), is there an API I can use to find the list of 20 commit Ids by using the original leaf commit Id as a parameter?

```
GetPullRequests(string commitId)
```

Ideally there would be a git rest API method to do this, but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: There’s no such things as pull requests in the repository.

Comment: Do you mean merged? To 20 branches??

Comment: yes, I mean merged to 20 branches. There would be 20 commit IDs, which I am looking for. I will update my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. We're supposed to use a PullRequestQuery and pass a list of commits as the input. It will return a dictionary of merged commit Ids for each commit we input. Below is the code to get all PRs for one commit Id.

```
  public void GetAllPullRequestsForCommit(Guid repoId, string commitId)
    {
        var query = new GitPullRequestQuery();
        var input = new GitPullRequestQueryInput() { Type = GitPullRequestQueryType.Commit, Items = new List<string>() { commitId } };

        query.QueryInputs = new List<GitPullRequestQueryInput>() { input };
        var response = _gitClient.GetPullRequestQueryAsync(query, repoId).Result;

        var samplePullRequest =  response.Results.SelectMany(x => x.Values).First().First().PullRequestId;
    }
```

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pull%20request%20query/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1#gitpullrequestqueryinput)

Comment: Looks like you’re using a language on top of git. Can you update the question tags to include it?

Comment: In my case I needed to have a second GitPullRequestQueryType I found this out by watching how the web browser interacts with vsts.

var lastMergeCommit = new GitPullRequestQueryInput() {Type = GitPullRequestQueryType.LastMergeCommit, Items = new List<string>() { commitId },};
var commit = new GitPullRequestQueryInput() {Type = GitPullRequestQueryType.Commit, Items = new List<string>() { commitId },};

Answer (score 1):

I found this question and answer useful (even though I was using postman, not C#) because [the microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20query/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), for my money, lacks a helpful explanation or example of what the input / body looks like for this request.

So, in addition to the answers here and the docs, this is how the input / resulting request body should be formatted:

```
{
  "queries": [
    {
      "type": "commit",
      "items": [ COMMIT_ID ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This can be verified if you head to *Azure DevOps > your repository > commits*, and click on a commit that's part of a PR. When this page loads, the network tab shows a request to **PullRequestQuery** with the body/payload formatted as above.

Comment: The Microsoft docs are not very helpful as they don't show a sample URL with sample body.  Your body example above helps but it's not clear the exact URL you are using along with the method (POST or GET?).  Can you expand your answer?  Also - what version of the API are you using